# java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: cp932?

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, mime-types, java

What type of content would cause this exception?

```
Caused by: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: cp932
        at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.forInputStreamReader(StreamDecoder.java:71)
        at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:100)
        at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain.getContent(text_plain.java:109)
        at com.google.code.javax.activation.DataSourceDataContentHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:803)
        at com.google.code.javax.activation.DataHandler.getContent(DataHandler.java:550)
        at com.google.code.javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.getContent(MimeBodyPart.java:639)
```

And why can't OpenJDK handle this encoding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Any text or text-based content that uses that character set / encoding!

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932), CP932 is an extension of Shift JIS ... which is one of the character sets that is used to represent Japanese text.

---

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/intl/encoding.doc.html), CP932 is in the "Extended Encoding Set (contained in lib/charsets.jar)".  If it is not in your install of OpenJDK, look for a yum / apt / whatever OpenJDK package that offers extra Java character set support.  Support for CP932 *in OpenJDK* is definitely available somewhere ...

It is also possible (though IMO unlikely) that OpenJDK doesn't recognize "cp932" as an alias for what it refers to as "MS932" and "windows-31j".

---

I checked [the code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/sun/nio/cs/ext/ExtendedCharsets.java/).

The issue is that Java (not just OpenJDK!) does not recognize the "cp932" alias at all.  The reason it doesn't recognize it is that the alias is **non-standard**.

The official (IANA endorsed) name for this encoding is "windows-31j", and Java also supports the following aliases by default:

- "MS932"
- "windows-932"
- "csWindows31J"

If you set the "sun.nio.cs.map" system property (i.e. using "-D...") to "Windows-31J/Shift_JIS", then Java will also recognize "shift-jis", "ms_kanji", "x-sjis", and "csShiftJIS" as being equivalent ... but this should only be used for backwards compatibility with old (1.4.0 and earlier) JDKs that didn't implement the real SHIFT-JIS encoding correctly.  (Besides, this doesn't solve your problem ...)

So what can you do?

- Reject / discard the content as invalid.  (And it is.)
- Find out where this content is coming from, and get *them* to fix the incorrect encoding name.
- Intercept the encoding name in the Google code *before* it tries to use it, and replace the non-standard name with an appropriate standard one.
- Use nasty reflective hackery to add an encoding alias to the private data structure that the Oracle code is using to lookup encodings. (Warning: this may make your application fragile, and lead to portability problems.)
- Raise an RFE against the Java SE requesting an easy way to add aliases for character encodings.  (This is a really long term solution, though you may be able to accelerate it by writing and submitting the proposed enhancement to the OpenJDK team as a patch.)